# Why doesn't this simple javascript statement work to check if the variable exists?

Tags: javascript

I'm processing some return JSON data.

Sometimes the JSON will return something I can access via

```
 var new_insert_id = data['internal']['new_insert_id'];
```

But sometimes this part of the json array data will not be returned at all, and so I need to skip this variable being set.

So I've written a simple check to make sure this data exists before trying to set the variable:

```
 if(typeof data['internal']['new_insert_id'] != 'undefined')
 {
     // if data['internal']['new_insert_id'] is defined, then..
     var new_insert_id = data['internal']['new_insert_id'];
 }
```

But when the JSON returns and there is no new_insert_id I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'new_insert_id' of undefined
```

And the line of code it points to as the culprit is the line of my *if* statement.

What am I missing? I thought my if statement would check if it exists or not, or do I need to do something else when working with arrays?

Comment: `data['internal']` doesnt exist apparantly. need to check if does first `if (typeof data['internal'] != 'undefined' && typeof data['internal']['new_insert_id'] != 'undefined')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Besides you can firstly check for existence of `data['internal']`, but you can also use the *pythonic* way, i.e. apply `try/catch` block:

```
try {
    var new_insert_id = data['internal']['new_insert_id'];
} catch (e) {}
```

Comment: This is so elegant and simple. I've never written code like this, or heard of phythonic! It worked perfect.

Comment: @cosmicbdog Yeah, sometimes it can be perfectly handy.

Comment: I'm guessing it is 'trying' to do something, and 'catching' the error if there is one? I have to read up on this.

Comment: @cosmicbdog Exactly so, but in `catch` block we have nothing, so we just skip the problem. Such constructions are very popular in [Python programming language](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html), and can also be applied in [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch).

Answer (score 2):

The statement you've written checks if `new_insert_id` property exists in 'internal', but it doesn't check if 'internal' exists in `data` variable.
This should work better:

```
if(typeof data['internal'] != 'undefined' && typeof data['internal']['new_insert_id'] != 'undefined')
{
     var new_insert_id = data['internal']['new_insert_id'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the error message says, that `data['internal']` is already undefined. you need to check that before:

```
if(typeof(data['internal']) != 'undefined' && typeof data['internal']['new_insert_id'] != 'undefined')
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to check `data['internal'] !== undefined` first :)

Answer (score 2):

in your test, you are testing if the property `['new_insert_id']` of `data['internal']` is undefined then you have trouble accessing it because `data['internal']` is undefined hence the error you get.

You have first to check if `data['internal']` is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

I think it because `data['internal']` is undefined.

So you need check `data['internal']` first.

```
if(data['internal'] && data['internal']['new_insert_id'])
 {
     // if data['internal']['new_insert_id'] is defined, then..
     var new_insert_id = data['internal']['new_insert_id'];
 }
```